# Change the caracteristic of the line drawn by OpenCV drawContours in Python

Tags: python, opencv, polymorphism, contour

Basically I would like to change the line by a character string (for instance a sequence of A). For that I need to overload the drawContours function. Does anyone have an idea how to prodeed ?

Comment: Write your own function?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I decided to use C++.

I have retrieved all the (x,y) contours coordinates and used putText to print text following the contour line.

The same method could also be use with python.